# Hive : Drop database

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to drop a big database in hive but i cannot find an option [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase) to skip trash, like `purge` for dropping tables. This may make trouble when a space quota is applied for the trash !

Any suggestion using only hive DDL commands ?

To be clear :

What i do :

```
Drop database <my_db> cascade;
```

What im looking for or something like:

```
Drop database <my_db> cascade purge;
```

Answer (score 2):

hive-default.xml

```
<property>
<name>hive.warehouse.data.skipTrash</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>
Set this to true if you do not want table data to be moved to trash while dropping table.
</description>
</property>
```

By Default this is set false.
This property will work for Hive 0.14.0 or above.

Comment: Drop all tables in a particular database and then drop that database. This way it will work for databases as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should find the path of data and delete it before dropping database.

Here is the command:

```sh
$ hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash <data_path>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HDFS data stored on disk and the table definitions in the Hive metastore are distinct entities.  As @congyh suggests, you can remove the data in the HDFS directory manually with `hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash <data_path>` and `drop db.table;`  As of Hive 0.11.0, you can also truncate the tables (delete HDFS data) before dropping them from the metastore.  As @Lovish saini suggests, while in a beeline CLI session:

`set hive.warehouse.data.skipTrash=true;
truncate table db.table;
drop table db.table;`

Comment: I know that they are distinct, i asked does there something like `PURGE` for dropping tables

Comment: As of Hive 0.11.0, `TRUNCATE TABLE`